# Are there any free currency textbox controls for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, textbox, currency

If not, what's the best way of sanitizing users' input (keyboard and pasting from the clipboard)?

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress is releasing version 9.2 of their controls this week which includes a masked edit control based on RegEx:

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/78946/270208.aspx#270208

Aside from that you're stuck hacking KeyDown and TextChanged events to cobble something together.  I've done a lot of that and I've got to say its not pretty and very hard to test!  I'm not aware of a free control at the moment that does this.